# $current_user->id() returns 0 when logged in for HTTP Middleware

Tags: 9, http-request

I have injected `currentUser` as a dependency into my HTTP middleware, but when I check the UID while logged in, the result is always 0.

I am logged in as an admin and refreshing the watchdog page; the log messages show the UID is always 0.  `$this->currentUser->isAnonymous()` also returns `1`, so my code is running at the wrong time.  However, I don't know how to adjust the priority to ensure the HTTP middleware runs at a time when I have access to the uid.

(Goal: I am trying to send site analytics server-side, so I want access to the UID and current path-- I've omitted injecting the current path in the example below, but to get the current path, the middleware must have a priority of less than 100.)

```
class Analytics implements HttpKernelInterface {

  /**
   * Current request.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected RequestStack $requestStack;

  /**
   * The wrapped HTTP kernel.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
   */
  protected HttpKernelInterface $httpKernel;

  /**
   * The current user.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  protected AccountInterface $currentUser;

  /**
   * Logger factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelInterface
   */
  protected LoggerChannelInterface $loggerFactory;

  /**
   * Creates a HTTP middleware handler.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface $kernel
   *   The HTTP kernel.
   */
  public function __construct(HttpKernelInterface $kernel, RequestStack $request_stack, AccountInterface $current_user, LoggerChannelFactoryInterface $logger_factory) {
    $this->httpKernel = $kernel;
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    $this->loggerFactory = $logger_factory->get('analytics');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function handle(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = TRUE): Response {
    if ($type === self::MASTER_REQUEST) {
      $user_id = $this->currentUser->id();
      $this->loggerFactory->info("Found UID: $user_id");
    }
    return $this->httpKernel->handle($request, $type, $catch);
  }

}
```

**MYMODULE.services.yml**

```
  MYMODULE.analytics_middleware:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Middleware\Analytics
    # Skip the first argument because it is injected by Drupal.
    arguments: ['@request_stack', '@current_user', '@logger.factory' ]
    tags:
      - { name: http_middleware, priority: 1000 }
```

For the priority, I tried 1000, 100, 0, -100, and -1000, all of which give the same result (UID = 0).

Comment: User authentication does not happen in a middleware, it's in the request event subscriber [AuthenticationSubscriber](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21AuthenticationSubscriber.php/class/AuthenticationSubscriber) with priority 300. So you would need to return the response from a request event subscriber with priority <300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User authentication does not happen in a middleware, it's in the request event subscriber [AuthenticationSubscriber](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21AuthenticationSubscriber.php/class/AuthenticationSubscriber) with priority 300:

```
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // The priority for authentication must be higher than the highest event
    // subscriber accessing the current user. Especially it must be higher than
    // LanguageRequestSubscriber as LanguageManager accesses the current user if
    // the language module is enabled.
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onKernelRequestAuthenticate', 300];

    ...

    return $events;
  }
```

So you would need to set the response in your own request event subscriber with priority <300, if you don't want to wait until the Drupal kernel has finished all request event subscribers and hands over control to the controller you have defined in a route which matches the requested path.